# VBA store string instead of range in ListFillRange ActiveX ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I've researched but been unable to find if it is possible to store a string instead of a Range in the ActiveX ComboBox.

My workbook has so many dependency's that it recalculates ComboBox(s) etc whenever the user enters any type of formula.  I've pasted values in the underlying formula-based range which helps and turned off calculation to no avail. Any guidance is appreciated.

Update - the combobox is bound and this is an example of setting the range.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Securities").OLEObjects("cboList").ListFillRange = "Securities!" & Range("mySecurities").Address
```

Comment: The confusion (in terms of the OP and answerer) I believe relates to the fact that their are two basic types of "Combo boxes" in Excel. FYI there is an "active X" combo box for the worksheet itself (embedded on as an OLEobject) and the MSForms based activeX combobox that is purely accessible from VBA.
For the OLEObject one I believe this needs to be bound to a range OR an aribtary set of string values (but not both at once). For the MSForms combobox, see the method outlined by Rachel below.

Comment: I didn't realize that activex had two "combo boxes" but this clarifies my confusion.  To be honest, I probably would've used the below version but my boss wanted it to look like this so I had no choice.  I take it from your comment that it's impossible.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: no problemo. yeah i think the two are designed for different purposes. The Forms variety is generally modal so unless you use a refedit control you wont even be able to select a Range at runtime (assuming you wanted to change it).

Answer (score 2):

Use the AddItem method of the ControlFormat property:

```
With Sheet1.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat
    .AddItem "Sunday"
    .AddItem "Monday"
    .AddItem "Tuesday"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the post.... Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case because I have it binded i.e. when you drop down it shows one list but when you select it is shows another.  I guess I could do a vlookup off of the return but would prefer if I could use something like .AddItem in the binded context.  Thanks much.